# Gist-embed with Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get **gist-embed** (https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed) working within my Angular app but with no luck.

It works no problem on my homepage (which is not part of the Angular app) but when I use something like:

```
<code data-gist-id="<gist-id>"></code>
```

within the app it won't show. There are no messages in the console to explain why though.

Could someone explain why and offer a solution?

Comment: You can try : https://github.com/kiran3807/another-angular-gist-embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($) {

  $(function() {
    // find all elements containing "data-gist-id" attribute.
    $('[data-gist-id]').each(function() {
      var $elem = $(this),
        id,
```

that lib is coded in such a way one cant really use it in angular,you'll have to look for a fork that offers a proper jquery plugin architecture you can use into a directive.That lib doesnt respect basic jQuery plugin architecture.

And no Error will show up because it's likely the `.each` will execute before your angular app runs.

Comment: As of June (version 1.8), its now a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As of June (version 1.8), the [gist-embed](https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed) project is now a jQuery plugin.

```
var $code = $('<code data-gist-id="474f6d7839fccffc4b2a"/>');
$code.appendTo('body').gist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to trigger "gist()" on the dom elements.

Try this, it worked for me very well.

```
            // register trigger gist on every template include
                $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {

                    // initialize gist on new elements
                    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                        if (typeof(angular.element(document).gist) === 'function') {
                            angular.element('[data-gist-id]').gist();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I put together a small library hoping to solve the problem.

Check it out : https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-gist-embed

Answer (score 0):

Chekout this angular module : https://github.com/kiran3807/another-angular-gist-embed

This allows you to include the gists in your angular project in the form of a directive, one of the attributes for which is the gist-id :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/another-angular-gist-embed.js"></script>
<script>
   angular.module('example',['another-angular-gist-embed']);
   angular.module.controller('exampleCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
       $scope.gistId = 'a85770344febb8e30935';
  }]);
</script>
</head>
</head>
<body ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <!-- This loads a gist with a specific id-->
    <gist-embed data-gist-id="gistId"></gist-embed>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Declaration : I am the author of this module